# How can I check if an unnamed slot is empty with StencilJS?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, stenciljs

This is how I would use my component

```html
<stencil-button icon="done">
   Hello world
</stencil-button>
```

I'd like to avoid to pass a slot named html fragment to my component every time

```html
<stencil-button icon="done">
   <span slot="text">Hello world</span>
</stencil-button>
```

---

In `render()` function, I'm used to hide an element if I dont's pass named slots to it:

```js
render () {
    return (
      <Host>
        { this.icon && <mds-icon name={this.icon} /> }
        { this.hasText && <mds-text typography={...}><slot name="text"/></mds-text> }
      </Host>
    )
  }
```

With **named slots**, I'm used to do this:

```js
componentWillLoad ():void {
  this.hasText = this.hostElement.querySelector('[slot="text"]') !== null
}
```

But with **unnamed slots** i cannot find a way to do it, I've tried some ways without success:

```js
render () {
    return (
      <Host>
        { this.icon && <mds-icon name={this.icon} /> }
        { this.hasText && <mds-text typography={...}><slot/></mds-text> }
      </Host>
    )
  }
```

I thought it worked by checking if I dont's pass `innerHTML` to it:

```js
componentWillLoad ():void {
  this.hasText = this.hostElement.innerHTML !== ''
}
```

This won't work because `innerHTML` changes in `componentDidRender()`.

So, how can I do that without be forced to pass an element?

Answer (score 0):

I dunno why it wasn't working, but this is working form me:

```js
componentWillLoad ():void {
  this.hasText = this.hostElement.innerHTML !== ''
}
```